# Trouble testing some twice with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an object with 2 items, each item contains an array of numbers.

```
selected: {
  item1: [1, 2, 3],
  item2: [4, 5, 6]
}
```

In a function I need to do something if the number passed to it isn't in either item. So for instance if 6 is passed do nothing, but if 7 is passed then do something.

The following returns true and false if one of the items contains the number

```
Object.entries(selected).forEach((itemParent)=>{
  console.log(
    itemParent[1].some((itemChild)=>{
      return itemChild === no;
    })
  )
});
```

But when I add the code below I get an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'some' of undefined`

```
Object.entries(selected)
  .forEach((itemParent)=>{
    itemParent[1].some((itemChild)=>{
      return itemChild === no;
    })
  }
).some((item)=>{
  return item === true;
});
```

Im using bable so I can use the latest ES6 syntax.

Comment: cause `itemParent[1]` is `2` or `5`... `itemParent` is array and `itemParent[i]` is element of that array

Comment: Your code inside the `forEach` callback doesn’t actually do anything. You check `itemParent[1].some((itemChild)=>{return itemChild === no;})`, but you don’t do anything with the result, so it’s immediately discarded. Then, of course, `forEach` returns `undefined`, so you can’t chain another `some` after it. Why are you using `forEach` anyway?

Comment: @Evans, what about our answers ?

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai Ive accepted one...

Comment: @Evans, yes, but you can upvote other solutions which includes our effort in order to gives you a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler approach I think:

```js
var selected = {
  item1: [1, 2, 3],
  item2: [4, 5, 6]
}
function exists(inputNumber) {
    return Object.keys(selected).some(key => selected[key].some(number => number === inputNumber));
}
console.log(exists(6));
console.log(exists(7));
```

And even simpler with Object.values:

```js
var selected = {
  item1: [1, 2, 3],
  item2: [4, 5, 6]
}
function exists(inputNumber) {
    return Object.values(selected).some(arr => arr.some(number => number === inputNumber));
}
console.log(exists(6));
console.log(exists(7));
```

Comment: Wouldn’t `Object.values` or `Object.entries` be better than `Object.keys`?

Comment: Yes, with Object.values, it will be simpler

Comment: @Faly, or using `concat` and `spread syntax`: `let contains= [].concat(...Object.values(selected)).includes(7);`

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai Smart idea, great

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the object is different than the given data, then you could nest `some` and check. Then return the result of checking.

```
return Object
    .entries(selected)
    .some(itemParent => itemParent[1].some(itemChild => itemChild === no))
```

Answer (score 2):

You are overcomplicating things. And btw, you are even using ES2017 features, so check whether Babel is configured accordingly.

Here is a short solution to your problem:

```js
const no = 7;

const selected = {
  item1: [1, 2, 3],
  item2: [4, 5, 6]
};

const containsNumber = Object.values(selected).some(array => array.includes(no));

console.log(containsNumber);
```

The reason you got an error message was that `forEach` does not actually return anything.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this error in your second example because [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) doesn't return the array but `undefined`, and `undefined` doesn't have any method named `some`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.values` in combination with `concat` function in order to obtain a more simple approach.

```js
let selected= {
  item1: [1, 2, 3],
  item2: [4, 5, 6]
};
let contains= [].concat(...Object.values(selected)).includes(7);
console.log(contains);
```